# Limitar acesso Simultâneo no Django

Tags: python, django, login

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma nativa do próprio framework Djang de limitar a quantidade de telas por usuário, já pesquisei sobre e não consigo encontrar nada que responda isso. Quero impedir de um usuário estar logado em mais de 1 tela, assim como acontece com a netflix e o whatsapp online. Agradeço qualquer resposta!

Comment: As sessões estão salvas em algum banco? Caso estiverem é só verificar se o usário tá logado, caso ele já esteja logado não permita o novo login. ou caso ele tente logar apague as sessões com o id dele da tabela de sessões

Comment: Isso sem dúvidas ajudou muito. 
Mas ainda estou tendo muita dificuldade em conseguir a sessão de um usuário específico. 
Já olhei pelo BD pra vê se achava alguma ligação, mas não encontro.

Comment: Está sendo salvo no DB? caso sim: `select count(*) from sessoes where user_id = 'id'` se a resposta for > 0 (Ou seja está logado!), não deixe ele logar!

Answer (score 1):

Voltei para dizer como resolvi meu problema.
Por ser novo ainda no Django tive que resolver do meu jeito e seguindo as dicas que foram me dadas nesse fórum.

**O QUE FIZ**

Sabendo o e-mail do usuário peguei o id dele.

`user = User.objects.get(username = mail)
 user_id = user.id`
Depois busquei todas as sessões e com o `for` procurei a sessão que tinha esse aí, mas para isso tive que decodificar antes.

`sessoes = Session.objects.all()

```
        for k in sessoes:
            z = k.get_decoded()  #decodifica e pega a sessao

            if(z['_auth_user_id'] == str(user_id)): # compara sessaoes encontradas com a sessao do usuario que tenta logar`
```

Depois o que fiz só excluir a sessão que tinha esse id.
OBS: Inclui também no settings `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True` para que a sessão expire quando o navegador for fechado.

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

O Django não oferece uma função nativa para fazer isso mas você pode implementar essa funcionalidade usando [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#middleware), existe algumas maneiras de como você poderia fazer isso nessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408823/django-how-to-prevent-multiple-users-login-using-the-same-credentials) do SO em inglês, recomendo que escolha a opção do middleware já que é um mecanismo da arquitetura do Django e que você pode reaproveitar em outros projetos e apps.

Algumas outras soluções:

- [Método usando `django-tracking`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821870/how-can-i-detect-multiple-logins-into-a-django-web-application-from-different-lo)
- [Método usando um modelo
  customizado com middleware, sessions e signals](https://dev.to/fleepgeek/prevent-multiple-sessions-for-a-user-in-your-django-application-13oo)